# DateFormatter is converting wrong

Tags: swift

Do you know why the following is not returning the right time?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-05-04 15:00")
print(date)
```

It returns `Optional(2017-05-04 13:00:00 +0000)`
I guess it has to do with timezones. If why do I need to know the timeZone on the server?

I just want to convert the value.

Comment: You are in the GMT+2 timezone. 15:00 at your location is 13:00 UTC. Everything is right!

Comment: I see, but the server is already giving me the right time in my timezone. Therefore I just need to convert without any timezone correction.

Comment: `Date` is an absolute point in time and has no timezone. Printing a Date (or getting its "description") always uses the UTC zone. Your date **is** correct. "2017-05-04 13:00:00 +0000" is the same point in time as "2017-05-04 15:00" in the GMT+2 zone.

Comment: Right, it works when adding dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC"). Thanks

Comment: That is only right if "2017-05-04 15:00" is UTC time and not the time in your timezone (as your wrote above).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```